# Цикл в node.js для записи в бд mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, циклы, асинхронность

Добрый день! Имеется массив данных. Необходимо каждый элемент поочередно записать в бд(mysql), естественно при запуске цикла столкнулся с асинхронностью ноды. Вопрос заключается в реализации. То есть как лучше реализовать: через промисы или есть какие-нибудь другие уловки для того, чтобы "подождать", пока запишутся все данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В node.js для работы с MySql я всегда работал с http://docs.sequelizejs.com/
Там почти все реализовано через промисы и вы можете сделать генератор, в котором напишите нужный вам цикл